# I am going up on the stairs

Tags: meaning

Is my following sentence correct? If not please correct it. I am not sure what preposition should be used with stairs in this sentence.

I am going up on the stairs to 10th floor of the building.

Answer (score 2):

No, the sentence has some errors. A corrected version of this sentence:

**I am going upstairs to the 10th floor of the building.**

'Upstairs' is an adverb that means "on or to an upper floor of a building."

Note that you need the definite article "the" before "10th" in order for this sentence to sound right.

**I am going up the stairs to the 10th floor of the building** is also acceptable, but it has a slightly different flavour: the use of the definite article "the"  before "stairs" draws more attention to the act of taking the stairs, perhaps to emphasize the choice not to take the elevator.

Comment: Thanks @Sova for your detailed answer. Could you please tell me what should be said when going down through stair.

Comment: The most common way to say it would be "I'm going downstairs." It's also possible (and grammatical) to say "I am going down the stairs" but, like with the above example, it places more emphasis on taking the stairs. This will a bit sound strange to native English speakers unless there is a good reason to emphasize your choice to take the stairs. It's a good general rule to just use the adverbs "upstairs" and "downstairs" instead of the prepositions "up/down" with the definite article "the" and the noun "stairs."

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sova. Sorry, one more question! if I go up or down through elevator what should I say.

Comment: That's called "taking the elevator [up/down] to the Xth floor."

Comment: @Amir, here are some practical sentences you can use: I am taking the stairs up to the 10th floor -- I need some exercise. ------ I am taking the stairs down to the lobby -- the elevator is taking too long.